# getPicklistValuesByRecordType does not work when page is ideal to pull the drop down value

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, community, lwc-wire-adapter

getpicklistvaluesbyRecordType -

In Experience Cloud : I have a site and have two sections on the site towards left pane. One section in left pane is home and the other is a customer care section. When I open this customer care I have a LWC which is a button and when I click the button it opens a case creation form in the site.

If I am on that case creation form using LWC method getpicklistvaluesbyRecordType - was able to load the values on a picklist field correctly. But If I am on the form where there is a picklist field whose drop down come from this method and If I stay ideal for say 30 minutes or so and I click on home tab on left pane and then again when I click on the customer care to create new case which has this dropdown, the form opens but this dropdown is greyed out.

If I refresh the page it works.

Note: I do not want the user to use controlling field to select the value and select the dependent picklist, hence I had to pass the controlling field value dynamically to pull the values from dependent picklist. I had to do this way because there are multiple projects using same picklist fields and record type and also the use case is just the dependent picklist to be shown.

Code:

```
@api userAudience;

  connectedCallback() {

        getUserDetails()
       .then(result => {          
            this.userAudience = result;
            console.log('the audience inside the connected call back is',this.userAudience);
            if(this.userAudience === 'PROJECTA'){
                this.userClassification = false;
            }
            else if (this.userAudience === 'PROJECTB'){
                this.userClassification = true;
            }
            else{
                this.userClassification = false;
            }
           
        }).catch(error => {
           
            this.showErrorToast(error);
        });


    }
```

// the above method calls Apex method to see the type of the user - whether it is user from Project A or project B.

// the below method shows how I am pulling the picklist values from the dependent field. I have a field "Type of user" on user which says user of Type A or B. I have the same field(Type of user) on case object with values Type A and Type B which is a controlling field. I am showing the values from dependent field only on the UI by passing the value of controlling field value dynamically using the user type.

```
 @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$abcrecordTypeId'})
    fetchPicklistValuesForABCField({error,data}){
        if (error) {
            console.log('unable to fetch values');
          }
        
       else if(data && data.picklistFieldValues){
        data.picklistFieldValues["Type of user"].values.forEach(optionData => {
            this.controllingPicklist.push({label : this.userAudience, value : this.userAudience});
        });
        this.dependentPicklist = data.picklistFieldValues["dependentField"];
    
        this.finalDependentVal=[];
     
        const selectedVal = this.userAudience;
            this.finalDependentVal.push({label : "--None--", value : "--None--"})
            let controllerValues = this.dependentPicklist.controllerValues;
            this.dependentPicklist.values.forEach(depVal => {
                depVal.validFor.forEach(depKey =>{
                    if(depKey === controllerValues[selectedVal]){
                        this.dependentDisabled = false;
                      
                        this.finalDependentVal.push({label : depVal.label, value : depVal.value});
                    }
                });
                 
            });
           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Async before the getpicklist wire adapter method and it worked.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your answer to use an actual code snippet.